# How do I modify the message notifier widget in the Unity global menu?

Tags: 11.10, unity, messaging-menu

I started to ask "What's this not-a-panel panel in Unity, and how do I control it?" but I've at least gotten as far as realizing it is the "global menu".

My global menu has a message notifier widget in place that scans my email, empathy, pidgin, etc. for new messages. I'd like to ...

- Remove Evolution from the menu (It shows me both Evolution and Thunderbird even though I don't have any email addresses set up on Evolution).
- Tell it to use Pidgin *or* Empathy -- for some reason it is currently showing me both.

I'm frustrated that right-click doesn't give me any additional options here. I can't even figure out how to quit Pidgin, since it is only in my message indicator, not in my launcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indicator menu items are in

`/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications`

so if you want to get rid of something, you can delete it from there. For example, delete

`/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/evolution`

to get rid of evolution. Note that this will affect all user accounts, and it will be difficult to get it back.

For a less permanent method, create the folder

`mkdir ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/ -p`

and copy the menu items you don't want into there

```
cp /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/evolution ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/
```

This will only show up for your user. Of course, you can remove items from the blacklist folder to get them back.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Empathy (ie. "Chat"). Despite having it in my blacklist folder I still see it. To remove it I had to uninstall empathy (see below).

Answer (score 0):

uninstall empathy and evolution

```
sudo apt-get purge empathy
sudo apt-get purge eolution
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

since i didnt understand your question to full extent i.m gonna explain

[image]

this is a screen shot
the app is runnning only if the little triange like next to broadcast is there next to ur other apps ie pidgin and thunderbird
[since i have configured TB, you see Mail]