# How do I modify the Unity Global Menu

Tags: 11.10, unity, panel, messaging-menu

I got some help with part of this question:  [How do I modify the message notifier widget in the Unity global menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76803/how-do-i-modify-the-message-notifier-widget-in-the-unity-global-menu)

But I'm wondering more broadly if there is a tool to tweak the Unity Global Menu. With a gnome panel I used to be able to right click and get the options right there. In Unity I can't see a way to access any options. Where are they?

I've looked at [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators) and [How to hide items in Unity's top panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74986/how-to-hide-items-in-unitys-top-panel) -- is there really no centralized management for this menu?

Comment: "tweak"?  what do you want to-do with the panel?

Comment: This has been on my mind too. Maybe the next version will have more options to hide stuff.

Comment: The messaging menu was the big one, but also the buttons are all b/w, which confuses me. Esp. since printing is gray scale and some indicators have real color icons.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: [How can I manually edit the unity top panel?](http://askubuntu.com/q/59922/28339) -- other folks want to modify the menu in other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are no central options for the panel. You can often install and uninstall indicators through the software center, although some of them I think need to be changed through the command line.

But in general, there are very few options for the panel. There's no default way to rearrange the indicators, provide auto-hiding, easily hide or show indicators, hide or show the global menu, change the location or size of the panel, change it's color, etc. These sorts of options have all been removed in Unity.

There's one or two settings you can change in CCSM. Changing the transparency comes to mind. But other than that, it's pretty much stuck the way it is.

Comment: This is a shame. I don't use the email client so it would be nice to hide it.

Comment: You mean from the message menu? Because the envelope is not just for email. It is for webfeeds (aka RSS), social networks, IM, file shares, email and anything else that is some sort of message, like a new voice mail on your answering machine.

Comment: @Finglas You can edit what appears in the messaging menu using the method outlined here http://askubuntu.com/questions/76803/how-do-i-modify-the-message-notifier-widget-in-the-unity-global-menu

Comment: Jo-Erlend Schinstad, I'm pretty frustrated by the fact that I can't seem to get under the hood of the messaging menu. I don't want RSS to show up there, I'd love for Skype and Tweetdeck to show up there. Weird how locked up it is.